# ';' expected.ts(1005) .I get an error and cannot run it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Typescript is not used. Why am I getting this error? It does not occur in any other component.
I have looked at the answers of other questioners but have not found any useful information. Can someone please help me?

The corresponding errors occur at the constructor function location, the shouldComponentUpdate function location, and the render function location.

```
const RowTextarea = () => {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.textArea = null;
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    if(this.props.input.value !== nextProps.input.value){
      if(isEmpty(nextProps.input.value)){
        this.textArea.setAttribute('rows', this.props.rows);
      }else{
        this.textArea.setAttribute('rows', this.props.rows);
        while(this.textArea.scrollHeight > this.textArea.offsetHeight){
          const tempRows = Number(this.textArea.getAttribute('rows'));
          this.textArea.setAttribute('rows', tempRows + 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The dialog box is covering the code above. Can you please add some of your code as plain text (formatted in a code block)? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're trying to mix class syntax and arrow function syntax, it won't work that way.

Comment: `RowTextarea` is a plain function, not a class. It cannot have a `constructor`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for sharing.

Changing from a function component to a class component worked.
It was really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).